# How to customize html5 audio player spectrum?

Tags: html

I would like to have custom html5 audio player like the one soundcloud has.
Can I use soundcloud widget on my site with customization? Or Are there any other players available on internet with source code so that I can customize them and use?

I am open to buy also.

Comment: Good question. I am also looking for a html5 audio player.

Comment: [This](http://badassjs.com/post/27056714305/plucked-html5-audio-editor-and-threeaudio-js), [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351147/html5-audio-visualizer), etc. Look around some